# How does a wizard or bard learn new spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

I can't find anything in the D&D 5e books about learning spells as an arcane spellcaster.

I have a question:

- As, say, a Wizard levels up and gets new spell slots, does he need to go to a library and find the spell somewhere? Could he learn a spell he saw someone else cast?

Comment: Related: [How does one find new spells?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49236)

Comment: I put it that way because there's other arcane spellcasters in the game. I understand that a divine caster such as a cleric would receive spells from the deity, and a ranger or druid would get them through their connection with nature. A sorcerer has innate casting ability so I'd think of them as D&D Jedi... but a Bard? Same as a wizard, I'd guess, since he's also an arcane caster.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## The Wizard

**At leveling up** you are allowed to simply **choose two spells from the wizard list** and declare that they are now in your spellbook. (PHB p.114: Learning Spells of 1st Level and Higher)

**But there's more!** You can build up your spellbook much quicker than that: see the sidebar "Your Spellbook" on p. 114 of the PHB. This describes the sort of process you mention, whereby you add to your spellbook by studying another wizards' copy, reading a scroll, or even through original research. (This, in my opinion, is the *sine qua non* of the wizard: the ability to build up such a large repertoire from which to prepare every day.)

See also [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/44580/23970) to [Is it possible for a wizard to change the spells in her spellbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44576/23970)

## The Bard

@DaleM's excellent answer:

> > You know four 1st-level spells of your choice from the bard spell list.
> >
> > The Spells Known column of the Bard table shows when you learn more bard spells of your choice. Each of these spells must be of a
> >     level for which you have spell slots, as shown on the table. For
> >     instance, when you reach 3rd level in this class, you can learn one
> >     new spell of 1st or 2nd level.
> >
> > Additionally, when you gain a level in this class, you can choose one of the bard spells you know and replace it with another spell from
> >     the bard spell list, which also must be of a level for which you have
> >     spell slots.
>
> **But there's no more!** Unlike the wizard, you can never know more spells
>   than this.
>
> The wizard is unique among spell casters in being able to acquire more
>   spells by finding them. Some casters like Clerics have access to all
>   of the spells on the list when preparing them and others like Bards
>   have a limited and immutable list of spells that they know.

Answer (score 25):

@nitsua60 has covered the wizard; for the bard (PHB p.53):

> You know four 1st-level spells of your choice from the
>   bard spell list.
>
> The Spells Known column of the Bard table shows
>   when you learn more bard spells of your choice. Each of
>   these spells must be of a level for which you have spell
>   slots, as shown on the table. For instance, when you
>   reach 3rd level in this class, you can learn one new spell
>   of 1st or 2nd level.
>
> Additionally, when you gain a level in this class, you
>   can choose one of the bard spells you know and replace
>   it with another spell from the bard spell list, which also
>   must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

**But there's no more!** Unlike the wizard, you can never know more spells than this.

The wizard is unique among spell casters in being able to acquire more spells by finding them. Some casters like Clerics have access to all of the spells on the list when preparing them and others like Bards have a limited and immutable (except for the one spell you can change each level) list of spells that they know.

Comment: It feels kind of weird to upvote two incomplete answers because each references and relies on the other. Isn't the standard to incorporate the other answer, so that each answer stands alone?

Comment: @GMJoe no, we can't allow either answer to become too powerful.

Comment: @GMJoe I'd first answered the question when there was no reference to bards. I'd started to edit my answer to include bards when Dale M posted his perfectly good bard-answer. I saw no need to steal Dale's thunder, as it were, and just referenced his. Just a weird artifact of timing and a shifting question....

Comment: So that this is a real answer on its own, [it's preferable that it answer the question independently](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/should-i-be-requesting-people-answer-the-question-independently) by including any necessary statements, and refer to other answers only to give due credit.