# Is there a way for a Bard to learn one more known spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, bard

Looking at the Bard progression table, Bards begin at level 1 with 4 spells known, and then gain (on average) 1 new known spell per level, until they cap at level 18. I'd like to know if there is a rule or guidance on how a bard could gain one single extra known spell through some kind of special training? For example, time between adventures can be spent to learn a proficiency in a new skill by spending 250 days (at 1gp per day) to train in said skill. Is there something similar for known spells?

I'm not looking for extra cantrips or spell slots, and I know the Magic Initiate feat can grant such an extra known spell (and casting it at level 1) if taken in the same class, in addition to 2 cantrips. But I'd like to avoid going as far as a feat for that.

Comment: I believe that this answer is relevant to your question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/68710/48249

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I see it, your options for getting additional spells will require you to spend resources:

1. Pick the College of Lore as your subclass specialization and receive 2 spells from any class which don't count against your bard spells known.(Magical Secrets).
2. Multi-class into another full caster class (Warlock or Sorcerer most likely) to sacrifice higher-level spell progression for some additional spells known.
3. Pick up the Magic Initiate (as you said) or Ritual caster feat.

Comment: Great point about the School of Lore. That is indeed what I was planning on taking and forgot about the level 6 "Additional Magical Secrets" benefit.

Comment: While subject to a DM willing to hand one out, Bardic Instruments (magic item[s]) possibly deserve a mention.

Answer (score 7):

You can get access to extra spells via wands and similar magical items. If you get a ring of spell storing you could get allies to place spells that you want into it.

A better feat for you to look at would be [Ritual Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/ritual-caster) (PHB, p. 169). You could use it to access a variety of ritual tagged spells from a class of your choice.

Otherwise there is no real official method of obtaining extra spells.

Comment: "You can cast racial spells using spell slots." - This is false, especially after the [2018 PHB errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) that edited every spellcasting class's Spellcasting feature to specify that their spell slots can be used to cast that class's spells (e.g. wizards' spell slots can be used for wizard spells). I don't think any racial trait that grants spells specifies that they're associated with any class.

Comment: I stand corrected. I'd thought that rule was still in place.